# Prove that $X_{(n)}/n$ tends to zero in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

Let there be given a sample from the distribution $F$ such that
$$ \lim\limits_{y \to \infty } y(1 - F(y) + F(-y)) = 0$$

Prove that $X_{(n)} / n \to 0$ in probability, where $X_{(n)}$ is order statistics.

My attempt to solve it
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X_{(n)}/n| > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|X_{(n)}| > n\epsilon) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(|X_{(n)}| < n\epsilon) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(-n\epsilon < X_{(n)} < n\epsilon) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < n\epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} < -n\epsilon) = 1 - (F(n\epsilon))^n + (F(-n\epsilon))^n$$

So, maybe from the initial statement it can be somehow deduce that the last tends to zero.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ 0 \leq (F(-n\epsilon))^n \leq F(-n\epsilon) $ and $ lim_{n \to \infty} F(-n\epsilon) = 0 $. Thus, $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (F(-n\epsilon))^n = 0~~(1)$.

Also, observe that $ \frac{n(F(n\epsilon) - 1)}{F(n\epsilon)} \leq n \log F(n\epsilon) \leq 0$, since $ \log x\geq \frac{x-1}{x} ~~\forall x>0 $.

Moreover, $ 0 \leq n(1-F(n\epsilon)) \leq n(1- F(n\epsilon) + F(-n\epsilon)) $ and $ \lim_{n \to \infty} n(1- F(n\epsilon) + F(-n\epsilon)) = 0$.

Therefore, $ \lim_{n\to \infty} n(1-F(n\epsilon)) = 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(F(n\epsilon) - 1)}{F(n\epsilon)} = 0 $, since $ \lim_{n\to \infty} F(n\epsilon) = 1$.

Consequently, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \log F(n\epsilon) = 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} (F(n\epsilon))^n = 1~~(2).$

Combine $(1)~ \& ~(2)$ and you are done.